# Help with adding and multiplying points on secp256k1

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation, secp256k1

I'm currently working on implementing digital signatures on the curve secp256k1 (for learning purposes only), and I'm having some trouble implementing ECDSA on curve secp256k1. As I understand it, this curve is a koblitz curve, which means it can't be written in the Montgomery form. Due to this limitation, I'm unable to use the Montgomery ladder.

Can anyone suggest how I can add and multiply points on the curve in this case? Any guidance or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Roadmap to implementing ECDSA on secp256k1 for educative purposes

1. Have low expectations:

   - Something slow if you stop at the end of 2, and not fast even if you go all the way of 3.
   - Something not safe from side-channel (and others) attacks for signature generation.
2. Dive in:

   - Get large-integer arithmetic running (that's built in Python, an bundled in Java), including modular inversion.
   - Implement point adding and doubling by the [standard technique from sec1](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.2.1).
   - Use [secp256k1 parameters from sec2](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1).
   - implement point multiplication by a scalar using straight double-and-add according to the binary representation of the scalar.
   - get SHA-256 running (that's bundled in Python and Java).
   - get [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1) running.
3. Optimize speed:

   - Use projective or Jacobian coordinates to eliminate most modular inversions, which are the bottleneck in 2.
   - Use [wNAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#w-ary_non-adjacent_form_(wNAF)_method) to perform less point additions.
   - Use  sliding window to the same effect.
   - Use Shamir's trick to about halve the number of doublings in signature verification.
   - Use the Koblitz-curve-specific technique [there](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44647-8_11).

Proofread and test along the way. Again, do NOT expect something secure for signature generation.